# How to custom dropdown with js inside loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> I'm making a forum web site(`html`+`Vue3`+`php`+`sql`), and there have a post system.
> Mostly, when we need to custom dropdown object, it always needs to initial the `fake dropdown object` with js. (or have the other way that IDK)

for example, I'm using the css framework「[`Tocas-UI`](https://tocas-ui.com/)」,and I got the some html objects below:

```html
<div class="ts floating dropdown icon button">
    <i class="vertical ellipsis icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item">Add</div>
        <div class="item">Edit</div>
        <div class="item">Share</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And `<div class="ts floating dropdown icon button">...</div>` can be used js `ts('.ts.dropdown:not(.basic)').dropdown();` to make it be a "`dropdown`" object.

[image: object be created after call the function .dropdown()]

Although it can only be used once to initial every object which have class `.ts.dropdown`, but I'm using the js framework `Vue3`, and when I using `v-for` to render every post (have one `fake dropdown object` in every post), it's not working on the object which are be created after I call the function `.dropdown()`.

---

So I was tried to put `ts('.ts.dropdown:not(.basic)').dropdown();` into loop, it stupid and also not working.

Here is the code in the v-for loop:

```html
<template v-for="post in posts">
<div class="item">
    <div class="ts mini circular image">
        <img src="default.png">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="header">{{ post.poster.nickname || post.poster.username  }}</div>
        <div class="middoted meta">
            <a>@{{ post.poster.username }}</a>
            <div>{{ Init.timeToStatus(post.datetime) }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="ts separated secondary icon buttons">
            <div class="ts floating dropdown icon button">
                <i class="vertical ellipsis icon"></i>
                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="item">Add</div>
                    <div class="item">Edit</div>
                    <div class="item">Share</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

So the question is... How can I make those `fake dropdown object` be initial with `ts('.ts.dropdown:not(.basic)').dropdown();` even have new post be added after page loaded.

Comment: My advice: Skip JS for a forum. Espacially if you sue databases you should work with a full server-sided language as PHP espacially sicne you already using PHP.

Comment: It for the some functions of post like `edit`、`remove`, so I want to use js to make a dropdown object to show those functions :(

And my posts is from the other page(api), and use `ajax` to get it then use `vue` to render it.

Comment: Most JavaScript modules will be removed In the latest Tocas UI 4 due to this kind of issues. The same problem happened with Semantic UI since they are always hardly integrate with frameworks like Vue, React. I'm looking for a better solution to provide an integration for frameworks, might reference about how people done this in Headless UI and Tailwind UI.

Comment: @YamiOdymel Hello, author of Tocas-UI :D Since I stopped using facebook, I haven't interacted with you. Whatever, thank you for replying , and expect the release ver.4 coming.

Comment: @YamiOdymel Yes, because of the those problems of js, I deprecated the Semantic-UI framework :(